# Simultaneous main()s for SBT-based project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, distributed

Say, you have sbt-based project targeting some distributed aims. That is, your project contains Play application(s) (with some subprojects hierarchy) as well as, say, few other own services, tools to fill test data in, load and so on.. You see, to develop the project you inevitably want to start many simultaneous main()s.

At the moment I have decided the problem this way: sbt terminal session is used to run Play, and Scala IDE is used for others. To eliminate any clashes I was forced to write own template engine and router for Play (that is eliminating managed sources in Play's terms).

OTOH, I don't want to be strongly sticked to the Scala IDE (or any IDE) having an opportunity to start simultaneously many main()s (tracking output of each of them) in terms of sbt sessions themselves.

What is your sbt-based developer's environment for distributed systems developing?

Comment: Does each project need to be its own separate process? Why not just run the code from different threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not immediately helpful, you may be interested in the backgroundRun task some of us are working on adding to sbt. For now the API is in this plugin code:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control/blob/master/ui-interface/src/main/scala/sbt/BackgroundRun.scala

It's just a version of run that doesn't
block and you can manage jobs much as you can in bash.

Supporting Play is harder than supporting generic run, it requires this PR: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3591

Anyway this isn't all published and working but working on it.

The best short term solution I think is to run multiple instances of sbt and be careful not to compile in more than one of them at once. If you get any weird build or classpath errors, do a clean and be sure it wasn't caused by multiple compiles stomping each other.

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks for the clarification of the current state. Is there a rough roadmap estimation remoting will be added to sbt?

Comment: sometime next year hopefully. you don't really need the remoting to use this backgroundRun feature, but we haven't published the plugin in any consumable way.